# Copying a folder into the root of an ear using Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am looking to move a folder into the root of an ear that I generate.

My build.gradle in my subproject look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

dependencies {
    deploy project(path: ':UiWeb', configuration:'archives')
    deploy project(path: ':ProviderWeb', configuration:'archives')
    deploy project(path: ':Business', configuration: 'archives')
    deploy project(path: ':Common', configuration: 'archives')
    deploy project(path: ':Domain', configuration: 'archives')
    deploy project(path: ':Translator', configuration: 'archives')
    deploy project(path: ':Properties', configuration: 'archives')


    earlib fileTree(dir: 'sharedLib', include: '*.jar')
    earlib fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}


ear {

    from("EAR/resources/properties/${environment}") {
        include "*.*"
        into "properties"
    }

    classifier environment()
    libDirName 'lib'

    deploymentDescriptor {
        applicationName = "app"
        displayName = 'EAR'
        description = 'app'
        version = '6'

        metaInf {
            from './META-INF'
            exclude 'application.xml'

        }

        webModule("UiWeb.war", "UiWeb")

        securityRole 'AllUsers'
    }

    manifest {
        attributes("Implementation-Title": "App",
               "Implementation-Version": "TEST",
               "Implementation-Vendor": "Company",
               "Build-By": "gradle",
               "Build-Date": new Date().toString());
  }

}
```

My trouble is the `from("EAR/resources/properties/${environment}")` as it is not actually copying the folder into the ear! I do not get any errors at any level of console output.

The `${environment}` is passed into Gradle using -Penvironment=xxx and I know that this works because the value is appended to the ears name.

Please, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass value for `environment` via property, then you should get it using `project.getProperties().get("environment")`

Try use this:

```
from("EAR/resources/properties/${project.getProperties().get("environment")}") {
    include "*.*"
    into "properties"
}
```

Don't forget to include `environment=` in project `gradle.properties`